# Marching Cubes (C++ to C#)

Tags: c++, pointers, marching-cubes

I am trying to implement marching cubes in C#, but I've come to a part where I don't understand the algorithm and I don't how to implement it.

`int Polygonise(GRIDCELL grid, double isolevel, TRIANGLE *triangles)`

The third argument I don't really understand. I know it's a pointer, but later on in the algo, when you set the triangles it appears as though the `triangles` variable is an array of the `TRIANGLE` struct:

```
int ntriang = 0;

for (int i=0; triTable[cubeindex,i]!=-1; i+=3) {
    triangles[ntriang].p[i  ] = vertlist[triTable[cubeindex,i  ]];
    triangles[ntriang].p[i+1] = vertlist[triTable[cubeindex,i+1]];
    triangles[ntriang].p[i+2] = vertlist[triTable[cubeindex,i+2]];
    ntriang++;
}
```

Notice the `triangles[ntriang]`. That doesn't make sense because before we set `triangles` to `TRIANGLE *triangles`. I also don't understand why It's a pointer.

Comment: Why doesn't `triangles[ntriang]` make sense? It simply uses `ntriang` to index into the array pointed to by `triangles`. The rest of the expression assigns something to the member `p` of the struct at the `ntriang-th` position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caller of `Polygonize` expects `*triangles` point to an allocated array long enough to contain all the triangles. The equivalent in c# can be a `TRIANGLE[]` or a `List<TRIANGLE>()`

Comment: with a list you have to add and then you can use [] operator as an array.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this function takes the GRID of voxels/cells and outputs the triangles. It is a pointer since you will get a list of triangles.